# Userform - Search&Update ability

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I’m new to StackOverflow and VBA coding and thanks to my C&P/editing skills, I’ve managed to make an amateur CRM for my own needs in my company.

[User form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rukyZ.jpg)

I’ve come up with an user form(you can find its screenshot attached) which stores the data in one sheet(Maindata) and also creates a new another one(Sheet name is getting its name from center ID textbox- so its dynamic) which contains that center’s specific data and financial projections.

Let me give you a brief overview of the spreadsheet;

Maindata: Data entry starts from A2 and goes to AU2, (47 columns in total) the spreadsheet hasn’t populated yet, but when it does it will be probably +400 row long.

Basically what I want to achieve is; Search&Update ability within user form. I can’t bring pre-registered data back to my user form. The search should bring partial matches as well, so there could be more than one registry when searched. To select the right one from search inquiry, I’ve added a list box that should give me the search results inside and when double-clicked, it should bring the whole row’s data back to user form. At the point of update, it should update/overwrite on the related row(Should not create a new registry) and it should update the dynamic named sheet’s(Which is created with the same name with “Center ID” back at the registry) specified cells.

To be more specific with the search&update;

1. A user will type into "textbox1"
2. Hit search button which is called "cbSearch"
3. Matching registries will be listed in "listbox1"
4. Upon double-click userform will be filled with the selected
   registery info.(Listbox will show 4 cloumns of data but after
   dclick, the rest of the information will be shown on the userform)
5. Update button should overwrite on the existing info on "maindata"
   sheet and the sheet that matches with it's center ID.

If you can show me how to fill a textbox with the selected item's info from listbox I can adapt it to the rest of the 46 columns :)

"A" column's info should go into = TB0
"B" column's info should go into = STN

I'm putting the code of the save button which has the %90 of the code in the userform.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If TB0.Value = "" Or STN.Value = "" Or cbCountry.Value = "" Or tbCity.Value = "" Then

If TB0.Value = "" Then
TB0.BackColor = vbRed
End If

If STN.Value = "" Then
STN.BackColor = vbRed
End If

If cbCountry.Value = "" Then
cbCountry.BackColor = vbRed
End If

If tbCity.Value = "" Then
tbCity.BackColor = vbRed
End If

    MsgBox "Please Fill The Required Fields", vbCritical
    Exit Sub

End If

If CP1.Value = "" And CP2.Value = "" And CP3.Value = "" Then

If CP1.Value = "" Then
CP1.BackColor = vbRed
End If

If CP2.Value = "" Then
CP2.BackColor = vbRed
End If

If CP3.Value = "" Then
CP3.BackColor = vbRed
End If

    MsgBox "Center Price Is Required", vbCritical
    Exit Sub

End If



'Make Daily_Tracking_Dataset active
Worksheets("MainData").Activate

'Determine emptyRow
Emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer Information
Cells(Emptyrow, 1).Value = TB0.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 2).Value = STN.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 3).Value = cbCountry.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 4).Value = tbCity.Text
Cells(Emptyrow, 5).Value = cbLab.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 6).Value = tba.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 7).Value = tbb.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 8).Value = tbc.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 9).Value = tbd.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 10).Value = ctb1.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 11).Value = ctb2.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 12).Value = ctb3.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 13).Value = ctb4.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 14).Value = ctb5.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 15).Value = ctb6.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 16).Value = ctb7.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 17).Value = ctb8.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 18).Value = ctb9.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 19).Value = ctb10.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 20).Value = ctb11.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 21).Value = ctb12.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 22).Value = ctb13.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 23).Value = ctb14.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 24).Value = ctb15.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 26).Value = tb11.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 27).Value = CP1.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 28).Value = CP2.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 29).Value = CP3.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 30).Value = CP4.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 31).Value = Pricingbox1.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 32).Value = Pricingbox2.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 33).Value = Pricingbox3.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 34).Value = Pricingbox4.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 35).Value = Pricingbox5.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 36).Value = Pricingbox6.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 37).Value = Pricingbox7.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 38).Value = Pricingbox8.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 39).Value = Pricingbox9.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 40).Value = Pricingbox10.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 41).Value = Pricingbox11.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 42).Value = Costtb1.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 43).Value = Costtb2.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 44).Value = Costtb3.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 45).Value = Costtb4.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 46).Value = Costtb5.Value
Cells(Emptyrow, 47).Value = VAT.Value


  myvar = ""

  For x = 0 To Me.lb.ListCount - 1
  If Me.lb.Selected(x) Then
  If myvar = "" Then
  myvar = Me.lb.List(x, 0)
    Else

    myvar = myvar & "," & Me.lb.List(x, 0)
    End If
  End If
 Next x

Cells(Emptyrow, 25).Value = myvar



Dim Newsheet, SheetName2 As String
Newsheet = STN.Text
SheetName2 = ActiveSheet.Name

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = Newsheet

Sheets("template").Visible = True
Sheets("Template").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(Newsheet).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


Range("A10").Value = STN.Value
Range("B10").Value = cbCountry.Value
Range("C10").Value = CP1.Value
Range("D10").Value = CP2.Value
Range("E10").Value = CP3.Value
Range("F10").Value = CP4.Value
Range("G10").Value = Pricingbox1.Value
Range("I10").Value = Pricingbox2.Text
Range("K10").Value = Pricingbox3.Value
Range("M10").Value = Pricingbox4.Value
Range("O10").Value = Pricingbox5.Value
Range("Q10").Value = Pricingbox6.Value
Range("S10").Value = Pricingbox7.Value
Range("U10").Value = Pricingbox8.Value
Range("w10").Value = Pricingbox9.Value
Range("y10").Value = Pricingbox10.Value
Range("aa10").Value = Pricingbox11.Value
Range("a12").Value = Costtb1.Value
Range("b12").Value = Costtb2.Value
Range("c12").Value = Costtb3.Value
Range("d12").Value = Costtb4.Value
Range("e12").Value = Costtb5.Value
Range("F12").Value = VAT.Value
Range("g12").Value = cbLab.Value
Range("h12").Value = tba.Value
Range("ı12").Value = tbb.Value
Range("j12").Value = tbc.Value
Range("k12").Value = tbd.Value
Range("b2").Value = ctb1.Value
Range("d2").Value = ctb2.Value
Range("f2").Value = ctb3.Value
Range("b3").Value = ctb4.Value
Range("d3").Value = ctb5.Value
Range("f3").Value = ctb6.Value
Range("b4").Value = ctb7.Value
Range("d4").Value = ctb8.Value
Range("f4").Value = ctb9.Value
Range("b5").Value = ctb10.Value
Range("d5").Value = ctb11.Value
Range("f5").Value = ctb12.Value
Range("b6").Value = ctb13.Value
Range("d6").Value = ctb14.Value
Range("f6").Value = ctb15.Value





Sheets("template").Visible = False



Dim cell As Range, ws As Worksheet
    With Sheets("MainData")   'Sheet with the hyperlink sheet names
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each cell In .Range("B1", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))   'Loop for each used cell in column A
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                Set ws = Nothing
                Set ws = Sheets(cell.Value)
                If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="", SubAddress:=("'" & cell.Value & "'!B1")
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With




End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you only have single column in a `ListBox` you can just use `Range("A1").Value2 = Me.ListBox1.Text` (or `.Value`). However, if the `ListBox` has multiple columns you need to get the position of the selected line. Unfortunately `VBA` has no direct way of doing this so we need to loop through the items in the list.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    With Me.ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                Me.TextBox1.Value = .List(i, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

This runs on click of the `ListBox` (you may want to change it for your code). Finds which item has been selected and returns the value in column 2 (rows and columns both start at 0)

[image: Demo]

***Search Function***
e.g. Search demo

```
Option Explicit
Dim Data As Variant
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.cboxCountry.List = Array("USA", "UK", "FR", "DE")
    Me.cboxLabCount.List = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    ' Update with your data
    With Sheet1
        Data = .Range("A1:D4")
    End With

    Me.ListBox1.List = Data
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Me.ListBox1.List = FilteredResults(Me.TextBox1.Value)
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim i As Long
    With Me.ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then Exit For
        Next i

        Me.tbCenterID.Value = .List(i, 0)
        Me.tbCenterName.Value = .List(i, 1)
        Me.cboxCountry.Value = .List(i, 2)
        Me.cboxLabCount.Value = .List(i, 3)
    End With
End Sub
Private Function FilteredResults(SearchValue As String) As Variant
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ResultCounter As Long
    ReDim tmp(LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2), LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1))

    If SearchValue = vbNullString Then
        FilteredResults = Data
    Else
        For i = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
            If Levenshtein(CStr(Data(i, 1)), SearchValue) Or _
               Levenshtein(CStr(Data(i, 2)), SearchValue) Or _
               Levenshtein(CStr(Data(i, 3)), SearchValue) Or _
               Levenshtein(CStr(Data(i, 4)), SearchValue) _
            Then
                ResultCounter = ResultCounter + 1
                tmp(1, ResultCounter) = Data(i, 1)
                tmp(2, ResultCounter) = Data(i, 2)
                tmp(3, ResultCounter) = Data(i, 3)
                tmp(4, ResultCounter) = Data(i, 4)
            End If
        Next i
        If ResultCounter > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve tmp(LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1), LBound(tmp, 2) To ResultCounter)
        End If
        FilteredResults = Transpose2DArray(tmp)
    End If
End Function
Private Function Transpose2DArray(tmpArray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ReDim tmp(LBound(tmpArray, 2) To UBound(tmpArray, 2), LBound(tmpArray, 1) To UBound(tmpArray, 1))

    For i = LBound(tmpArray, 1) To UBound(tmpArray, 1)
        For j = LBound(tmpArray, 2) To UBound(tmpArray, 2)
            tmp(j, i) = tmpArray(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Transpose2DArray = tmp
End Function
Private Function Levenshtein(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim l1 As Integer
    Dim l2 As Integer
    Dim d() As Integer
    Dim min1 As Integer
    Dim min2 As Integer

    l1 = Len(s1)
    l2 = Len(s2)
    ReDim d(l1, l2)
    For i = 0 To l1
        d(i, 0) = i
    Next
    For j = 0 To l2
        d(0, j) = j
    Next
    For i = 1 To l1
        For j = 1 To l2
            If Mid(s1, i, 1) = Mid(s2, j, 1) Then
                d(i, j) = d(i - 1, j - 1)
            Else
                min1 = d(i - 1, j) + 1
                min2 = d(i, j - 1) + 1
                If min2 < min1 Then
                    min1 = min2
                End If
                min2 = d(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
                If min2 < min1 Then
                    min1 = min2
                End If
                d(i, j) = min1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Levenshtein = 1 - (d(l1, l2) / Len(s2))
End Function
```

[image: Demo Search]

I've updated this with a demo search function. You will need to update the `UserForm_Initialize` with your data range. You can change quite a few things for this and it could also be easily expanded on but it is a quick demo. I'm also using the `TextBox1_Change` event instead of a search button click but again this can be easily changed. The code uses a Levenshtein Ratio for it's search function to try and compare similar strings. Again there are other ways of achieving this.

You will also need to configure it depending on what you want to search against. This considers each column of your data set individually and will return any that match.

Comment: Hello @tom thanks for your reply. I've edited my listbox code accordingly, it works perfect,  I mean it does bring the data to my userform but I'm still having search problems. I don't know how to make a search. I've a code that only brings the whole data to my listbox which is basically not a search :) How do you think I should proceed from here ?

Comment: @BatıkanGüven You'd need to filter that data dependent on your search criteria.

Comment: could you please give me a starting point for that, as I'm quite new to VBA 
 so I can work on it? My search button and listbox code looks like this at the moment <pre> Private Sub cbSearch_Click()
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim rng     As Range
Dim MyArray
Set ws = Sheets("Maindata")


Set rng = ws.Range("A1:au" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)

With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear
    .ColumnHeads = False
    .ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count
     MyArray = rng
    .List = MyArray
    .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50"
    .TopIndex = 0
End With
End Sub<code>

Comment: Take a look at my update. It's not quite as simple as here's a drop in search function that works as it'll depend on your requirements but I've put together a demo of one which you can configure.